# Minimum sample size to obtain population mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, average, sampling

Knowing the average of a population, how could I evaluate an expected sample average based on k_sample?

Data Info:

Variance and standard deviation:

$\sigma^2= 0.18500975256337462$

$\sigma=0.43012760032736175$

population : 3572 
value range : [0,60] 
mean: 1.2140032642853837

Histogram : frequency (y) vs score value (x) 
A few outsiders (x,y): (5,1),(8,1),(13,1)
[image: Histogram y:frequency & x:score value]

Comment: For absolute equality, unless all companies have the same value, $5000$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I understand but what about within x% of certainty?

Comment: There are **two** numbers we need, the error allowed in how closely we approximate the true mean, and what probability of error is allowed (often this is $5\%$). And even given these numbers, we need some information about the variance.

Comment: I can calculate the variance.
Say the error allowed in how closely we approximate is alpha
and the probability of error is sigma.

What would be the math?

Comment: Now we are at a more conventional problem. We need to assume the distribution is reasonable, so that we can use the Central Limit Theorem. If some detail is supplied, I should be able to give an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I've added more info about the data.